# how to load json file using jsonp and jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I have a file abcjsn.json in remote url like:  **http://abc.com/abcjsn.json**
The content of the Json file is :

```
    {
"root": {
    "node": [
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "Europe",
                "description": "European Curricula"
            },
            "node": {
                "@attributes": {
                    "id": "2553",
                    "name": "Ireland",
                    "description": "Irish Curricula"
                },
                "node": {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "id": "3083",
                        "name": "Primary School Curriculum",
                        "description": "Primary Curriculum"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "7",
                "name": "Middle East",
                "description": "Middle Eastern Curricula"
            }
        },
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "North America",
                "description": "North American Curricula"
            }
        },
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "South America",
                "description": "South American Curricula"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

and i am using the following code to access it:

```
var url = "http://abc.com/abcjsn.json"

        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          data:  {},
          success: function(data) { alert(data); },
          jsonp: 'jsonp'
        });
```

But i am not able to access it. it newer goes to alert.
how can i do it.

Comment: The server has to support JSONP. If it does not, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The server should return you something like

`myCallBackFunction`('{....}')

and your `myCallBackFunction` should call  j`Query.parseJSON(...)`

and then it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the server is wrapping the JSON in a function, then this should work:

```
var url = "http://abc.com/abcjsn.json?callback=?";

$.getJSON(url, function(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

Notice the `callback` parameter in the url.

Comment: I have to  do access from cross domain.

Comment: If it isn't local, can you share with us the URL for where the JSON is?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 var url = "http://abc.com/abcjsn.json"

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data:  {},
      success: function(data) { alert(data); }
    });
```

**EDIT**

JsonP is removed because if you are using jsonp the source you are donwloading should look like this

```
myLocalFunc({
    // Contnet of that json;
});
```

When it is loaded your function called `myLocalFunc` is executed. The one you are calling is just a json. I assumed that you have crossdomain access.

**EDIT**

If you don't have cross domain access then you have to implement a proxy in your server that will request remote server and give the result to you or user some crossdomain techniques discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190354/jquery-check-external-link/9190444#9190444). Note however that they are applicable only if you have an access to the target domain.

Comment: I can't access that. Take a look at http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&callback=myCallback - notice how the json object is passed as a param to the function `myCallback`

Answer (score 0):

## This will allow you to access from `Cross Domain`:

---

The `JSON` in your question above should be wrapped in a `function` call:

### STEP 1: Make the `function` available:

Ensure that you have `myCallbackFunc` defined on the `global window object` *beforehand* (this function will be executed as soon as the `script-tag` is loaded).  For ex:

```
window.myCallbackFunc = function(jsonData) {
   // do something with the jsondata
}
```

### STEP 2: Prepare the `remote JSON file`:

Ensure that the remote `JSON file` is calling the `myCallbackFunc function` with the `JSON` passed to it.  For ex:

```
myCallbackFunction({
  "root": {...}
});
```

### STEP 3: Prepare and load the `script` tag:

Then, you should request this file with `script` tag like so:

```
var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.src =  "http://example.com/abcjsn.json?callback=myCallbackFunc";
scriptEl.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
```

**Note :** We need to add the `callback` in the `query-string` with its value having the `name` of our `function` (`myCallbackFunc` in this case). This function will be executed once the file is loaded.

Good Luck...